# UITableView: using moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath: and reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: together appears broken

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios5, uikit

I want to use iOS 5's nifty row-movement calls to animate a tableview to match some model state changes, instead of the older-style delete-and-insert.

Changes may include both reordering and in-place updates, and I want to animate both, so some rows will need `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`.

But! `UITableView` appears to be just plain wrong in its handling of row reloads in the presence of moves, if the updated cell shifts position because of the moves. Using the older delete+insert calls, in a way that should be equivalent, works fine.

Here's some code; I apologize for the verbosity but it does compile and run. The meat is in the `doMoves:` method. Exposition below.

```
#define THISWORKS

@implementation ScrambledList // extends UITableViewController
{
  NSMutableArray *model;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  model = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
           @"zero",
           @"one",
           @"two",
           @"three",
           @"four",
           nil];
  [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:
#ifdef THISWORKS
                                              @"\U0001F603"
#else
                                              @"\U0001F4A9"
#endif
                                                                              style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                             target:self
                                                                             action:@selector(doMoves:)]];
}

-(IBAction)doMoves:(id)sender
{
  int fromrow = 4, torow = 0, changedrow = 2; // 2 = its "before" position, just like the docs say.

  // some model changes happen...
  [model replaceObjectAtIndex:changedrow
                   withObject:[[model objectAtIndex:changedrow] stringByAppendingString:@"\u2032"]];  
  id tmp = [model objectAtIndex:fromrow];
  [model removeObjectAtIndex:fromrow];
  [model insertObject:tmp atIndex:torow];

  // then we tell the table view what they were
  [self.tableView beginUpdates];
  [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:changedrow inSection:0]]
                        withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight]; // again, index for the "before" state; the tableview should figure out it really wants row 3 when the time comes
#ifdef THISWORKS
  [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:fromrow inSection:0]]
                        withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
  [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:torow inSection:0]]
                        withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
#else // but this doesn't
  [self.tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:fromrow inSection:0]
                         toIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:torow inSection:0]];
#endif
  [self.tableView endUpdates];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source boilerplate, not very interesting

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return model.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@""];
  if (cell == nil)
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@""];
  [cell.textLabel setText:[[model objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] description]];
  [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"this cell was provided for row %d", indexPath.row]];
  return cell;
}
```

What the code does: sets up a tiny model (small mutable array); when a button is pushed, it makes a small change to the middle element of the list, and moves the last element to be the first. Then it updates the table view to reflect these changes: reloads the middle row, removes the last row and inserts a new row zero.

This works. In fact, adding logging to `cellForRowAtIndexPath` shows that although I ask for row 2 to be reloaded, the tableview correctly asks for row 3 because of the insert once it's time to actually do the update. Huzzah!

Now comment out the top #ifdef to use the moveRowAtIndexPath call instead.

Now the tableview *removes* row 2, asks for a fresh row *2* (wrong!), and inserts it in the final row-2 position (also wrong!). Net result is that row 1 moved down *two* slots instead of one, and scrolling it offscreen to force a reload shows how it's gone out of sync with the model. I could understand if `moveRowAtIndexPath` changed the tableview's private model in a different order, requiring the use of the "new" instead of "old" index paths in reloads or model fetches, but that's not what's going on. Note that in the second "after" pic, the third and fourth rows are in the opposite order, which should't happen no matter which cell I'm reloading.

[image: before state]

[image: after one button push, delete-insert style]

[image: after one button push, move-style]

My vocabulary has grown colorful cursing Apple. Should I be cursing myself instead? Are row moves just plain incompatible with row reloads in the same updates block (as well as, I suspect, inserts and deletes)? Can anyone enlighten me before I go file the bug report?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm running into the exact same issue.

Comment: Nope! I filed a bug report that was closed with "not enough information" and a request to test it under ios6 (which I have not gotten around to, but if you're having the problem it's probably not fixed, and UICollectionView might have a similar problem.)  Two workarounds I'd expect to work are: do two separate begin/endUpdates blocks, one for reloads then one for moves/inserts/deletes; or skip reloadRowsAtIndexPaths entirely and locate/repopulate the appropriate cells by hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just spent some time playing with your code, and I agree; looks like it just doesn't work.

This whole area is a bit under-documented, but they don't actually say that you can mix `moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:` with reload methods. It *does* say in the that it can be mixed with row-insertion and row-deletion methods. Those seems to work if I modify your code to exercise those instead. So, you might be asking for an enhancement, not filing a bug. Either way, I'd definitely send it to radar.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Radar filed. If Apple ever resolves it, I'll append the resolution.